# Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint - caused by join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've found thousands of issues with the error converting data type nvarchar to bigint but no solution for my specific problem. I have a generic table DynamicArticle_ParameterResult where the value field can contain everything (numbers / text).

If I do subqueries based on a join **(ArticleResultID = DAAR.ID)** I get 'Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint':

```
SELECT        OSL.GroupName AS MAINGROUPNAME, DAAR.SalesLineID, DAAR.SalesID, DAAR.ID, spt.number + 1 AS SUBNO,   (SELECT        Value
                           FROM            DynamicArticle_ParameterResult AS DynamicArticle_ParameterResult_9
                           WHERE        (ArticleResultID = DAAR.ID) AND (Name = 'Panel_Dx')) AS Panel_dx,
                         (SELECT        Value
                           FROM            DynamicArticle_ParameterResult AS DynamicArticle_ParameterResult_8
                           WHERE        (ArticleResultID = DAAR.ID) AND (Name = 'Panel_Dy')) AS Panel_dy,
                         (SELECT        Value
                           FROM            DynamicArticle_ParameterResult AS DynamicArticle_ParameterResult_7
                           WHERE        (ArticleResultID = DAAR.ID) AND (Name = 'Panel_Dz')) AS Panel_dz,

                         (SELECT        Name
                           FROM            ProductManagerConfig.dbo.Colors
                           WHERE        (Id =
                                                         (SELECT        TOP (1) Value
                                                           FROM            DynamicArticle_ParameterResult
                                                           WHERE        (ArticleResultID = DAAR.ID) AND (Name = 'Panel_Color')))) AS COLORNAME, OSL.GroupName AS Soort, ST.LoadDay, ST.RouteNumber, ST.RouteOrderNumber, ST.SalesNumber, 
                     ST.ProductionNumber, Products.GroupName, Products.FullNameFROM            DynamicArticle_ArticleResult AS DAAR INNER JOIN
                     ProductManager_Products AS Products ON Products.ItemID = DAAR.ItemID INNER JOIN
                     SalesTable AS ST ON ST.Id = DAAR.SalesID INNER JOIN
                     OrderSalesLines AS OSL ON OSL.SalesLineID = Products.SalesLineID AND OSL.Depth = 0 INNER JOIN
                     SalesLines AS SL ON SL.Id = Products.SalesLineID INNER JOIN
                     master.dbo.spt_values AS spt ON spt.type = 'P' AND spt.number < SL.Quantity WHERE        (Products.Id IN (116994,116993)) AND (DAAR.Name = 'Panel' OR
                     DAAR.Name = 'KlassiekPaneel')
```

If I put a filter right in the subquery (**(ArticleResultID IN(1075728,1075669)**) it runs fine?

```
SELECT        OSL.GroupName AS MAINGROUPNAME, DAAR.SalesLineID, DAAR.SalesID, DAAR.ID, spt.number + 1 AS SUBNO,   (SELECT        Value FROM            DynamicArticle_ParameterResult AS DynamicArticle_ParameterResult_9
                           WHERE        (ArticleResultID IN(1075728,1075669)) AND (Name = 'Panel_Dx')) AS Panel_dx,
                         (SELECT        Value
                           FROM            DynamicArticle_ParameterResult AS DynamicArticle_ParameterResult_8
                           WHERE        (ArticleResultID IN(1075728,1075669)) AND (Name = 'Panel_Dy')) AS Panel_dy,
                         (SELECT        Value
                           FROM            DynamicArticle_ParameterResult AS DynamicArticle_ParameterResult_7
                           WHERE        (ArticleResultID IN(1075728,1075669)) AND (Name = 'Panel_Dz')) AS Panel_dz,

                         (SELECT        Name
                           FROM            ProductManagerConfig.dbo.Colors
                           WHERE        (Id =
                                                         (SELECT        TOP (1) Value
                                                           FROM      DynamicArticle_ParameterResult
                                                           WHERE        (ArticleResultID IN(1075728,1075669)) AND (Name = 'Panel_Color')))) AS COLORNAME, OSL.GroupName AS Soort, ST.LoadDay, ST.RouteNumber, ST.RouteOrderNumber, ST.SalesNumber, 
                     ST.ProductionNumber, Products.GroupName, Products.FullName FROM            DynamicArticle_ArticleResult AS DAAR INNER JOIN
                     ProductManager_Products AS Products ON Products.ItemID = DAAR.ItemID INNER JOIN
                     SalesTable AS ST ON ST.Id = DAAR.SalesID INNER JOIN
                     OrderSalesLines AS OSL ON OSL.SalesLineID = Products.SalesLineID AND OSL.Depth = 0 INNER JOIN
                     SalesLines AS SL ON SL.Id = Products.SalesLineID INNER JOIN
                     master.dbo.spt_values AS spt ON spt.type = 'P' AND spt.number < SL.Quantity WHERE (Products.Id IN (116994,116993)) AND (DAAR.Name = 'Panel' OR
                     DAAR.Name = 'KlassiekPaneel')
```

Is there a way to prevent this converting error?

Kind regards,

Mike

Comment: either clean up your data, or create a temp table that only includes valid entries and join to that instead.

Comment: You can join to a subquery that will only produce numeric DAAR.ID values.

Comment: your comments made me review my joins, found the problem!

Comment: could add isnumeric(daar.id) = 1 in the join

Answer (score 0):

Turned out my join to ordersaleslines caused the problem. Although it returned one row per product. I removed it and now it runs fine.